# image search not sending to channel on discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm building a discord bot that sends google image based on the keyword entered in command. When I run this code, I don't get an error but it does not execute.

```js
let args = message.content.substring(Prefix.length).split(" ");

switch(args[0]) {
  case "search":
    (async () => {
      const searchQ = args[1];
      results = await google.scrape(searchQ, 6);
      message.channel.send(results[0].url);
    });
    break;
}
```

Comment: Are you using this in a switch statement? Otherwise, that would result in syntax errors.

Comment: yes i am , i didnt include the beginning of the switch statement i didnt think it would be needed but i'll edit to add it

Comment: Have you checked the value of `args`? You should also fix your code as that `split` won't work this way and will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Yes before i put in in an async function i did a console log to see if the args was working properly and it was